# How to remove word in URL use htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I can't figure out how to redirect a link from https://www.example.com/cms/pagename to https://www.example.com/pagename

I am using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cms/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

I just want to remove CMS word from the URL.

Comment: So what is your actual issue? Remember that we cannot _guess_ that.

Comment: i just remove CMS word into my current URL.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not an answer to my question. You just repeated something you already wrote.

Comment: Check this old answer that helped me with same problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430099/htaccess-hide-directory-from-all-urls-in-website

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^cms/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

How it works:

Above rule is matching URL pattern, that starts with `cms` and have something like `/cms/pagename` and puts `pagename` in `$1`.

It makes an external redirection to `/pagename`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, note that it is redirecting not rewriting so when you call `https://www.example.com/cms/pagename` it will take you to `https://www.example.com/pagename` so it is upto you that it will work or not that way if are asking for rewriting please mention.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cms/(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```